# Is it true that for every polynomial $P(x)$, there exist an integer $n$ so that $Q(x)=P(x)+n$ is irreducible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for every polynomial $P(x)$, there exist an integer $n$ so that $Q(x)=P(x)+n$ is irreducible over the rational numbers? If not, what are the conditions of $P(x)$ so that there exist an integer $n$ so that $Q(x)=P(x)+n$ is irreducible? If $n$ is not an integer but a rational number, will the statement still correct?

I tried to use the Eisenstein criterion, but I couldn't make any progress from that.

Comment: use the fact that $Q(x)$ is irreducible iff $Q(x^{-1})$ is so, then your statement  tell you that it is possible to  add any terms of the form $nx^d$ where $d$ is the degree of $Q$. Then use Eisenstein after multplying for a prime which does not divide $a_0$ and summing $x^n$

Comment: @ALG That gives us irreducible  $pP(x)+n$. Can we find a prime $q\gg p$ such that $pP(x)+n$ is still irreducible in $\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z[X]$? If so, we can divide out the $p$ again ...

Answer (score 0):

We can choose the constant term to be coprime to all other coefficients, so the polynomial is primitive. Then by Gauss's lemma we know that irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now suppose that $f(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, it's reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, so $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ for some non-constant polynomials $g, h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

If the constant term of $f$ is prime, then since $f(0)=g(0) h(0)$, we have that the constant term of $g$ or the constant term of $h$ is $\pm$ the constant term of $f$.

Then, if we choose the constant term of $f$ to be extremely large, then either $g$ or $h$ must also have that large constant term. Thus one of the other coefficients of $f$ must also be extremely large.

Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Why does another coefficient have to be extremely large?? Isn’t it possible that the sign difference sort of “balances” that out? Like when you compute the final coefficient you have an equally large coefficient somewhere else.